# Cisco機器のVLAN仕様について

Tags: network

VLANにno ip addressの状態で設定している機器に対して、
指定のアドレスを付与すると構成上で発生するリスクは何ですか？

通常Vlan2で通信を可能としているとして、そのVlan2にIPアドレスの付与、
新たにVlan2を経由する機器の追加

既存でVlan2で通信している機器は影響がありますか？
OSPFで経路交換も行っています。

Comment: 構成も何も示されていないので回答不可能な質問です。何もつながってないルータにアドレスを付与したところで何も起きませんし、アドレスを振るべきでない理由があるインターフェースにアドレスを振ってしまえばトラブルが発生するでしょう。文章がおかしい点も含めて内容を見直してみてください。